# The component inside ng-content is instantiated twice

Tags: angular, ngoninit, angular2-ngcontent, ng-content, angular-component-life-cycle

I am using Angular 4 and I have a component 'X' which is basically a collapse-expand component. It wraps whatever is provided to it and collapse and expand it on clicking. It looks similar to below one.

```
<div>
    // some X related DOM here
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

I have another component 'Y', which I place within the 'X' component, like:

```
<x>
   <y [someAttribute]="someAttribute"> </y>
</x>
```

Now I have realized that the 'Y' component is instantiated twice i.e, the constructor, ngOnInit, ngOnChanges everything gets called twice.

Can it be a problem with using `<ng-content>` (I am still not completely sure). If Yes, how should I handle this to call my 'Y' component only once as I need to have component 'Y' wrapped within the 'X' only.

Edit: I missed adding earlier in the question that I am using `ngxPermissions` library to display '' conditionally. So its more like:

```
<x>
   <ng-template [ngxPermissionsOnly]="validPermissions">
       <y [someAttribute]="someAttribute"> </y>
   </ng-template>
</x>
```

Comment: Why are you using Angular 4 in 2019?

Comment: You are most likely using `<y>` somewhere else in your project.

Comment: That obviously was my first thought too, but unfortunately isn't the case.

Comment: Do you have any `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` in the template where you are using `<y>`?

Comment: Infact Yes. I missed adding that part in the question, but yes I am using `ngxPermissions` library to display '<y>' conditionally.

Comment: Try removing `*ngIf` and see if that fixes it. Most likely the condition is mutating from true/false causing the component to flicker.

Comment: check closing tags , if there is typo with <y><y> instead of <y></y>, it will be called twice

Comment: @NagaSaiA Did that bro. Even that is not the case.